# Hololens2 BackGround Removal

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, azure-communication-services

I have a curiosity of changing Hololens2 MR to VR,

I'm creating Education Program for Factory Workers using Unity MRTK,

Actually, Hololens2 Device has transparent Lens, so, When workers are watching Animations for 3D Model's disassembly and assembly, This real world's Stuffs are disturbing to make workers focus on the education. Are there any ways to make this real world's stuff as black or can i remove the background of it in Hololens2 View?

Additional Question: I tried to create a Video Calling System by Azure Spatial Calling and WebRTC, but both didn't work. My Unity Version is 2020.3.35f and I'm using MRTK2, Are there any ways to create Video Calling System? if it is existed, i'll be thankful to get reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

The HoloLens 2 device, designed for mixed reality experiences, overlays digital content onto the real world through its transparent lenses. Therefore, it’s not possible to ‘remove’ the view of the real world. To meet your requirements, consider creating a large black environment in the Unity scene to block out the real world.

For the creation of a video call system, you can use [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture?view=winrt-22621) to create a custom solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. for creating a large black environment, do i need to set alpha color for it?

Comment: the HoloLens does not render black, it will be shown as transparent.
[HoloLens add light to the world. Black pixels are fully transparent, while brighter pixels are increasingly opaque.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/rendering-overview)

Comment: Thank you for the corrections! Indeed, black won’t work due to the physics. Moreover, this method won’t entirely obscure the real world as a VR headset would, even when using very bright color.

Answer (score 0):

> Holographic devices have additive displays – Holograms are created by adding light to the light from the real world – white will appear brightly, while black will appear transparent.

and

> Rendering dark colors - Because of the nature of additive displays, dark colors appear transparent. A solid black object will appear no different from the real world. See Alpha channel below. To give the appearance of “black”, try a very dark grey RGB value such as 16,16,16.

=> Using something dark it is impossible for the HoloLens to overlay the real environment. You need to use something light.

This said you can for sure use e.g. Unity's blue default skybox which is quite bright to overlay the real world. It will never reach fully opaqueness though.

See [Color, light, and materials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/color-light-and-materials) and [Designing content for holographic display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/designing-content-for-holographic-display)